# C# How to map files from an external project in a treeview

Tags: c#, reflection, blazor

I want to map a external project files in a treeview with reflections.

The external project that i want to map into a treeview goes as following:

[image: TreeStructure]

How do i load this information from an external project into something i can use reflection on? I also only want to keep the files that has .razor extension.

To give you guys some context. I want to build an translation application so that you can load the razor pages from an external solution and make a json file that corresponds with each razor page.

Example: translate.nl.json

```json
{
  "She/Center": {
    "cases":  "gevallen"
  },
  "She/Pages/Example2": {
    "title": "titel"
  }
}
```

Comment: I think it is not possible. After a Blazor project is compiled, .razor are "normal" classes. You can't tell apart if the class was been a .cs file or a .razor file. The visual instruction has been replaced with calls to ``RenderTreeBuilder``. This would include all potential references to any translation logic you have in mind. 
That doesn't mean you can't do it at all. But it has been done before the project is compiled. You could for instance write a code analyzer that is executed within the build process and produce this file you have in mind or creating a .NET tool.

Comment: Is it possible to just map every class in a treeview then?

Comment: Sure, you can load an assembly only for reflection purposes. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/how-to-load-assemblies-into-the-reflection-only-context). Does this helps?

Comment: yes , thank you. I saw that every .razor file in our projects derived from either Component or ComponentBase. That way i am pretty darn sure that my reflection got the right files which i then pour in a treeview  PS. Greetings from MudBlazor btw :)